# Post javascript variables to separate .PHP file (Using Ajax?)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two files, one runs calculations in PHP once and stores them into variables in javascript. The second file holds mySQL query to be sent to database. How can I send the javascript variables from the first file, too the second file and store them as variables.

-I am loading the second .php file using a .load() function. So it is not refreshing and re-  directing to the second .php file.

Is this possible to do with out ajax?
If it is only possible with ajax, how do you set it up (new to ajax) ?

```
$("#st").click(function()
{
var s = $("#st").val();
var a = $("#AA").val();
var t = ((s*1)*(a*1)+(a*1)*(1/3)).toFixed(2);
var c = (t*95).toFixed(2);
var text = $('#st').children("option:selected").text();
document.getElementById('Tim').innerHTML ='<p>'+ t +' </p>';
document.getElementById('Obj').innerHTML ='<p>'+ text +'</p>';
document.getElementById('Tot').innerHTML ='<p>$'+ c +'</p>';
});

var Customer = <?php echo json_encode($q);?>;
var Dr= <?php echo json_encode($o);?>;
var Pd = <?php echo json_encode($p);?>;
var Qp = <?php echo json_encode($a);?>;
var Qs = <?php echo json_encode($r);?>;
var Cam = <?php 
        if($Camera==1){
            $CameraOutput = "XL";
            echo "XL";
            }

        if($Camera==2){
            $CameraOutput = "SL";
            echo "SL";
            }
    ?>;
```

Comment: pass data to second php from GET?

Comment: Getting data from a client (i.e. javascript) to the server (i.e. PHP) requires some form of connection, so you'll need a POST/GET/etc, which may or may not use AJAX.  If you're question is really how to submit and process via AJAX, there's dozens of tutorials on that you can find online.  If you get stuck with the implementation, show us some code, and we can try and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX is an acronym for asynchronous JavaScript and XML. If you want to run your second php file without redirecting to it, you can use AJAX because it will run your second php file 'in the background'. AJAX with JQuery is extremely easy to use aswell.

Taken from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Example: Save some data to the server and notify the user once it's complete:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: I understand this. BUT, I have two questions. First is "John" and "Boston" your variables you are posting? Second, how would I grab these variables on the second.php file?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder sorry, just thought that jQuery is exactly what he's looking for as it is a considerably easier than without it.

Comment: @deacs: Yes, but if the person isn't using it, it's not useful. Of course, in this case, they are!!

Comment: @user2592451: That's an important tag to put on your question. :-)

Comment: @user2592451 yes, in this case you can replace 'John' and 'Boston' with your own variables with their own 'names' (name and location in this case). In your php file you can grab the data with `$_POST['name']` & `$_POST['location']`

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the extra help, deacs.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: You mentioned in a comment on another answer that you're using jQuery, so I've edited the below.

> Is this possible to do with out ajax?

Yes, but you probably don't want to. You'd do it by creating a form element, setting its `action`, setting its `method`, adding fields to it, and `submit`ing it:

```
var form;
form = $("<form>")
    .attr("action", "/path/to/php/file.php")
    .attr("method", "POST");
$("<input type=hidden>")
    .attr("name", "fieldName1") // I'm assuming hardcoded field names
    .val(fieldValue1)           // And values coming from variables
    .appendTo(form);
$("<input type=hidden>")
    .attr("name", "fieldName2")
    .val(fieldValue2)
    .appendTo(form);
form[0].submit(); // Note the [0], so we're using `submit` on the actual HTMLFormElement
```

Note that the response will replace the current window.

> If it is only possible with ajax, how do you set it up (new to ajax) ?

There are thousands of examples out there. :-) Here's another:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  "/path/to/php/file.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"fieldName1": fieldValue1, "fieldName2": fieldValue2},
    success: function() {
        // Called if the request succeeds
    },
    error: function() {
        // Called if the request succeeds
    }
});
```

Comment: +1, I think you meant `field.value = fieldValue1;` and `field.value = fieldValue2;` instead of overwriting the name :)

Comment: What is the difference between your fieldName1 and fieldValue1? Also how do you locate these values in the second.php file?

Comment: @MrCode: Oops! (Feel free to just fix that kind of thing. :-) )

Comment: @user2592451: The field names are the names of the parameters you're sending to the PHP file. The values are the values of those parameters. So for instance, if you did `field.name = "foo"` and `field.value = "foovalue`, in your PHP `$_POST["foo"]` would be `"foovalue"`. (And similarly if you use `encodeURIComponent("foo") + "=" + encodeURIComponent("foovalue")` instead, in the ajax example -- the bit before the `=` is the name, the bit after is the value).